# Edit / Reedit question

Tags: discussion, editing, specific-question

[Do we need RSS buttons?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92382/do-we-need-rss-buttons)

So, this is the question. As you can see, the part of question up clearly doesn't add up anything. I've edited it, then a user does a rollback. I've edited it again, then he did another rollback.

Please, edit the question so it can be without this part about reading the whole question.

Comment: Weird, I could have *sworn* I'd tried editing that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw the beginnings of that edit war yesterday after you edited it and he reverted it.  For the record [here is a direct link to the edit diffs](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/posts/92382/revisions#rev-arrow-87768aca-ca6d-4357-beb2-781fd78f00cb).

I don't think your edit was bad, but I think that the original poster has edited their question in a way that clarifies it forcefully.   They were getting unhelpful answers and they have over-emphasized the details to prevent that.   In this case, I think that duplication can stay.   It makes the question better and clearer.  I have rejected your attempt to edit the question again.

It is almost never appropriate to apply the same edit after it has been reverted.  Edit wars lead to hurt feelings and unhappy users.   At the point that an edit has been reverted but you think it is needed, you should get a moderator involved.  You did well to bring up the issue here in meta.  You could also choose to flag the question for moderator attention.

Since your feelings may be hurt now Josip, I want to say that I appreciate your contributions to this site.   You spend a lot of time here and have done good work.  Please continue.

Comment: Thanks for clarification Stephen. I'll leave it be.

Comment: @JosipIvic I also like your being here on this site. Just saying...

Comment: Thanks guys :) hehe